# call template twice with similar parameters

Tags: xslt, parameter-passing, xslt-2.0

right now I have an xml file like this:
Basically all tags appear twice, but with prefixes `sideA` or `sideB`

```
<root>
    <sideA_foo>abc</sideA_foo>
    <sideA_bar>123</sideA_bar>
    <sideA_foobar>xyz</sideA_foobar>
    <!--many more sideA... tags -->

    <sideB_foo>def</sideB_foo>
    <sideB_bar>456</sideB_bar>
    <sideB_foobar>uvw</sideB_foobar>
    <!--many more sideB... tags -->
</root>
```

then I have a template like this

```
<xsl:template name="template1">
    <xsl:param name = "foo"/>
    <xsl:param name = "bar"/>
    <xsl:param name = "foobar"/>
    <!-- many more params -->

    <!-- do anything here -->
</xsl:template>
```

Is there an elegant way to call this template twice with all of its params,

- `<xsl:with-param name = "foo" select = "sideA_foo"/>` etc.
- `<xsl:with-param name = "foo" select = "sideB_foo"/>` etc.

without wirting all of this very verbosely, which I hate?

Comment: You mean more elegant than just... well, calling the template twice? It would be insightful to know [_why_ you need to call it twice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Then, perhaps we can suggest the best way to do it. We'd need a well-formed input XML and your complete current stylesheet.

Comment: In general using <xsl;call-template> is not an "elegant" way to write XSLT so that is probably why you are in this dilemma.

Comment: @ Mathias Müller, you are right that I might have to reconsider my whole structure at some point, which I will do when I find the time. The answer given by michael.hor257k is close to my actual problem in principle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way you could consider:

Given an **example input**:

```
<root>
    <sideA_width>5</sideA_width>
    <sideA_length>7</sideA_length>
    <sideB_width>6</sideB_width>
    <sideB_length>3</sideB_length>
</root>
```

the following stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <output>
        <xsl:call-template name="side-area">
            <xsl:with-param name="side" select="'sideA'"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:call-template name="side-area">
            <xsl:with-param name="side" select="'sideB'"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="side-area">
    <xsl:param name="side"/>
    <xsl:param name="width" select="*[name()=concat($side, '_width')]"/>
    <xsl:param name="length" select="*[name()=concat($side, '_length')]"/>
    <xsl:element name="{$side}_area">
        <xsl:value-of select="$width * $length"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
   <sideA_area>35</sideA_area>
   <sideB_area>18</sideB_area>
</output>
```

Note, however, that explicit naming of elements is more efficient - sometimes *much* more efficient. The *really* elegant solution would be to normalize your input before it gets to you, so that it looks more like (for example):

```
<root>
    <rect id="X">
        <width>5</width>
        <length>7</length>
    </rect> 
    <rect id="Y">
        <width>6</width>
        <length>3</length>
    </rect> 
</root>
```

Comment: I'm not convinced there would be a noticeable (if any) efficiency gain and explicit naming of elements reduces extensibility because you have to change the stylesheet whenever the element names change. The best example of the utility of not using explicit names is the identity template.

Comment: @IheOnwuka Extensibility is not a goal of mine.

Comment: That's ok. The advice is for the benefit of the OP.

Comment: Thanks! I agree my approach is not very elegant, and I should probably reconsider it. For now, this helps me a lot, though.

Comment: so, if I think deeper about this example, what would be a more elegant solution if I want to get the area of a rectangular X whose sides are identified with the tags `X_length` and `X_width` (this is not my actual problem, but equivalent in principle)

Comment: @WilliFischer If you don't want to specify explicitly `X_length * X_width` (and then `Y_length * Y_width`, and so on), then the best solution would be for the person that provides the input to change the format. That's what I meant by "*The really elegant solution would be to normalize your input before it gets to you.*"